How to freeze row/columns in excel using VBA without splitting the window
I have a macro in which one of the tasks it does is to freeze the top row and leftmost column. However when I tried to use the below codes it would also split the window which is not what I want. Is there any other way to freeze panes without having to splitting the window? Many thanks:)
With ActiveWindow
.SplitColumn = 1
.SplitRow = 1
End With
ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True


the .SplitColumn property creates a split window. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.window.splitcolumn

This question may help.

You are welcome @Michael ... if the answer was useful as well consider up-voting it and accepting it.

I would love to! But I can't seem to find an upvote option? I can only upvote the other one posted by Black Cat for some reason

Try to apply this instead of your posted code.
Range("B2").Activate
ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True

FreezePanes freezes the active range top/left corner row and column.
